# React Components not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a page created using React. Up until now everything was working great. But now the page loads and as soon as the page is loaded all components freeze and I cannot interact with them. It is important to note that the browser is working fine and it is **not** the browser that freezes.
If it helps, I am using webpack to host the page.

Here is a sample.

[image]

Basically I have a component that is like a parent to all other components. The parent component gets data from a server and passes along to other components. 
The parent also passes along methods that I can use to call from children component and interact with server again and this is basically the pattern through all the project. I have sadly no idea why it started freezing even though everything including styles loads perfectly. I just cannot interact with it and press buttons and such

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: What were you doing at the time it froze? Were you adding click event handlers? Or...

Comment: When you're asking code-related questions (which is what SO is for) not including any code is counter-productive. There's nothing here anyone can use to help.

Comment: This usually means there has been an error that has halted the render cycle. It can also be related to the version of react. What version are you using?

Comment: @christopher I am using the latest version of React. But what you mentioned regarding Render Cycle is a good clue.

Comment: @arvind Can you give us the version number and can you edit your post to use the code insertion feature ('{}' in the editor) and actually put your code in, so we can see how it works. Also, can you give us an idea of what's in `./FilterLevel01Data` please?

Answer (score -1):

One thing that can freeze things is if in the onClicks you do:

```
<button onClick={this.setSector('legal')}>
```

rather than:

```
<button onClick={() => this.setSector('legal')}>
```

Comment: i check it now. I have a lot of those but not on a button on a div

Comment: @NicolaPedretti I don't have something that is like what was mentioned in the previous comment. Another thing I checked was inside the chrome developer tools > Elements, there is no DOM except for the outermost div. I mean no of the components are even part of the DOM and yet i can see the page fully loaded.

Comment: @arvind , it is just too difficult for us to answer with what you gave us! try to at least show what you were doing when it happend and post some code

Comment: @NicolaPedretti I totally understand and I know it is really hard to help without any code sample.  But I upload a snippet now,

Comment: @NicolaPedretti It's something which has crashed my apps before when I was a beginner to react. I'm trying to help the guy...

Comment: @user1775718 Thanks for your input, I looked through my code you were right  I had inline javascript in my components.
Plus as NicolaPedretti mentioned about life cycle of components I realized I use setState inappropriately so my components would render one after the other without stopping. I will try to post an answer when I have made it work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @NicolaPedretti Thanks for the help as well